# Using two equations, creating a single equation with the same solutions as the original two?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am a little confused about the notion of creating a single equation (from two other ones) which has the solutions of both other equations.

For example, let my two equations be $u=v$ and $x=y$.

A book I am reading suggests that we can form a single equation with the solutions from both by the process:
$(u-v)^2 + (x-y)^2 = 0$.

I guess I am just confused about squaring the differences...wouldn't
$(u-v) + (x-y) = 0$ serve just as well?

Comment: wouldn’t $u=0$, $x=5$, $v=3$, $y=2$ show that your guess is wrong?

Comment: Hint: You want the only solutions of the combined equation to be the solutions of the separate equations.  This happens with the sum of squares of differences equalling zero, but not with just the sum of differences.

Comment: $a^2 + b^2 = 0 \implies a=0 \cap b=0$ (for real values) thus has only two solutions.  $a+b=0 \implies a = -b$ and thus has infinite solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since any number squared is positive (or zero) consider when we add two numbers $a,b \geq 0$ to get zero $(a+b = 0)$. So we see $a$ and $b$ have to be zero. So

$$(u-v)^2 + (x-y)^2 = 0 \iff u=v \quad \& \quad x=y $$

Things break down if we don't force them to be positive like in

$$ (u - v) + (x-y) = 0$$

This may mean $u = y$ and $v =x$ instead for example.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I am mistaken, I think that the equation you seek is $(u-v)(x-y)=0$. In this, each equation keeps its identity and characteristics, even though it is combined with the other into a single equation.